# C++ class variable returning gibberish

Tags: c++, function, class, variables

I'm having trouble with one of my C++ homework assignments. We're using a class to print out a list of phone numbers, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the number variable to print the defaults we're supposed to use with our constructors.

If any of you could point me in the right direction, with an example or the like, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class PhoneNumber { //This class will help the user make a list of phone numbers)
        private:
                int countryCode; //Stores the Country Code e.g. +1
                int areaCode; //Stores Area Code e.g. (925)
                int number; //Stores Number e.g. 754-6978
                char type; //Stores the "type" of number. e.g. 'H' for home, 'B' for business, 'C' for cell.
                int year; //Stores the year the number was added, for some odd reason.
        public:
                PhoneNumber(); //Empty constructor
                PhoneNumber(int ccode, int acode, int num, char line, int year);
                PhoneNumber(int num, char line = 'B');
                PhoneNumber(int acode, int num, char line = 'C');
                void setCountry(int ccode);
                void setArea(int acode);
                void setNumber(int num);
                void setType(char line);
                void setYear(int yr);
                int getCountry() const;
                int getArea() const;
                int getNumber() const;
                char getType() const;
                int getYear() const;
                bool doubleDigits() const;
                void printNumber() const;
                void printPhoneNumberStats() const;
};

//The Default Constructor
PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber() {
        void setCountry(int ccode  = 43);
        void setArea(int acode = 800);
        void setNumber(int num = 8675309);
        void setType(char line = 'H');
        void setYear(int year = 1981);
}

//Fill out the Phone Number class
PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(int ccode, int acode, int num, char line, int year) {
}

PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber(int num, char line) {
}

PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber (int acode, int num, char line) {
}

int PhoneNumber::getCountry() const {
        return countryCode;
}

int PhoneNumber::getArea() const {
        return areaCode;
}

int PhoneNumber::getNumber() const {
        return number;
}

char PhoneNumber::getType() const {
        return type;
}

int PhoneNumber::getYear() const {
        return year;
}

bool PhoneNumber::doubleDigits() const {
}  

void PhoneNumber::printNumber() const {
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
}

void PhoneNumber::printPhoneNumberStats() const {

}
```

Those are all my functions. Then there is the int main() that we are required to use.

```
int main() {
        PhoneNumber firstNum;
        PhoneNumber secondNum(39, 415, 867666, 'B', 2012);
        PhoneNumber thirdNum(1212121);
        PhoneNumber fourthNum(1234566, 'C');
        PhoneNumber fifthNum(925, 4392181);
        PhoneNumber sixthNum(925, 5512346, 'H');
        firstNum.printNumber();
/*      firstNum.printPhoneNumberStats();
        secondNum.printNumber();
        secondNum.printPhoneNumberStats();
        thirdNum.printNumber();
        thirdNum.printPhoneNumberStats();
        fourthNum.printNumber();
        fourthNum.printPhoneNumberStats();
        fifthNum.printNumber();
        fifthNum.printPhoneNumberStats();
        sixthNum.printNumber();
        sixthNum.printPhoneNumberStats();
*/
        return 0;
}
```

If you can explain *why* I'm getting garbage when I attempt to print the **number** variable, and how to fix it, I would be grateful.
Of course, any other advice would also be appreciated.

Thank you!
Caitlin

Comment: maybe your professor has an office hour where he or she can answer questions?

Comment: Some constructor don't assign elemnts to the data memebers

Comment: @akonsu He does, but I wasn't able to get the help I needed because other students took up his time.

Answer (score 2):

Your `PhoneNumber` default constructor (`PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()`) doesn't actually initialize any of the member variables;

```
PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber() {
    void setCountry(int ccode  = 43);
    void setArea(int acode = 800);
    void setNumber(int num = 8675309);
    void setType(char line = 'H');
    void setYear(int year = 1981);
}
```

These lines do not initialize anything - they are declaring functions, they're not calling the existing functions in the object.

To have a default constructor that initializes the member values you can do this:

```
PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber()
    : countryCode(43), areaCode(800), number(8675309), type('H'), year(1981)
{
}
```

Or if you want to use the "set" functions, call them this way:

```
PhoneNumber::PhoneNumber() {
    setCountry(43);
    setArea(800);
    setNumber(8675309);
    setType('H');
    setYear(1981);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`number` is never initialized.  Your `printNumber()` method should build `number` (which needs to be a `string` if you want the `-` in it) from the other members of the class, THEN print it.

So, your `printNumber()` method needs to look more like this...

```
void PhoneNumber::printNumber() const {
    number = //whatever you need to do to initialize it
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
}
```

Unless you're going to use your `constructor` methods to initialize `number`.